# Access or inspect Chrome localstorage on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I need to inspect the localstorage of a web application on the iOS Chrome browser.

Any ideas on how to access it?

Comment: Could you find any way to do it? If yes, please post the answer

Comment: No I haven't @ChiragMongia :(

Answer (score -1):

I've used this npm package before to debug on iOS Chrome:
http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/03/Remote-Web-Debugging-with-weinre/

I've also used alerts (gross, I know) to inspect data in localStorage, the window, ajax requests, etc.